# Do you need to call close if you already flush to make content survives unexpected reboot?

Tags: python, file

I'm writing to a file and I call flush() after I'm done.  Is it safe to force quit the program say pulling the power plug without calling close() on the file?  Is calling flush() sufficient that the file won't become corrupt.

Comment: For *pulling the plug*, you need `fsync()`, not just `flush()` or `close()`. Potentially even more than that if it's a newly-created file and its directory may not have been sync'd to disk either.

Comment: ...`flush()` and `close()` are both adequate to ensure that other programs running on the system can see your changes; they're not adequate to ensure that those changes survive an unclean shutdown of the OS. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So flush() and fsync() in that order is sufficient?  I have the file writing in a loop and calling close is a hassle.

Comment: Yes, `flush()` and `fsync()` in that order is sufficient (generally speaking, details about directories potentially also needing to be forcibly flushed notwithstanding).

Comment: @bakalolo why are you calling `close()` and not using `with`?

Comment: Would not be better to use with? Here is a short and simple tutorial that explains the with statement. https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Comment: @ArmandoPerez, if the OP is, say, appending content in a loop, putting the entire loop inside one `with` block and avoiding the need to re-open on reentering the section of that loop (with its attendant performance overhead, but *not* actually ensuring a flush-to-disk) doing the append makes sense.

Comment: yes the with was better choice I didn't really know how to use it but I just read up on it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure that content is flushed *to the operating system* (and is visible to other running applications), either `flush()` or `close()` will suffice (which is to say, you don't need both).

To ensure that content is flushed *to disk*, you also need to add [`os.fsync()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync) or [`os.fdatasync()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fdatasync). Do note that in the case of a newly-created (or newly-renamed) file, you need to worry about whether the directory was flushed as well.

---

By the way -- if you care about being *really* sure things get to disk, the classic presentation [Eat My Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMe7hf2G1po) is worth your time and attention.

Comment: Do you need to use the os.open() function to use os.fsync()?  I'm openign the file right now using open().

Comment: The file object created with `open()` has a `fileno()` function you can call to get a FD number to pass to `fsync()`. That's demonstrated in the upstream documentation I linked to.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I think you might have gotten things mixed up a little; neither `fsync` nor `fdatasync` guarantee that the directory entry will be written. To do that, you need to `fsync` a file descriptor for the directory. The difference between `fsync` and `fdatasync` is that `fsync` guarantees metadata like `atime` and `mtime` will be flushed.

Comment: @user2357112, I was trying to not make any assertions about the directory at all, but clearly failed at that. Modified appropriately.

Comment: What does "directory was flushed as well." mean? As in, you can send a command to the OS to make a directory and it might get terminated before it completes? That doesn't lead to a circumstance where you try to write to a file in a directory that hasn't been "flushed" to exist though, right?

Comment: @roganjosh, what do you mean by "completes"? Typically, a directory's creation is completed as soon as it's fully reflected by the VFS layer, visible to other applications, etc; that doesn't mean the changes were flushed to disk and going to survive reboot. Watch the linked presentation -- I don't have the time to recount everything in it, and if I tried, I'd probably get half the details wrong.

Comment: I'm getting myself confused here but the misunderstanding is definitely on my side. I can understand that writing (and flushing) to a file is a buffered process, but my understanding of this dialogue is that the directory might not be in place (as per the quote I gave)

Comment: See the section "The atomicity not durability argument" in https://thunk.org/tytso/blog/2009/03/15/dont-fear-the-fsync/ (from one of ext4's core developers) for some discussion of relevant issues from an authoritative source.